# Javascript regular expression to strip HTML tags with certain attributes but keep the inner text

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this HTML strings:

```
let string = '<span class="resource-child-type">device</span> (<span class="resource-child-instance">10.212.7.161</span>) > interface (<span class="resource-child-instance">10.212.7.161_interface</span>)';
```

And I want to remove all  with class `resource-child-instance` but I want to keep the text within the tags. So the output would be:

`<span class="resource-child-type">device</span> (10.212.7.161) > interface (10.212.7.161_interface)`

Currently, I'm using this regex:
`let regexp = /(<span(?: \w+="[^"]+")* class="resource-child-instance"(?: \w+="[^"]+")*>([^<]*)<\/span>)/g;`

However, this will match everything the opening `<span>` to the enclosing `</span>`. So is there a way for me to get the inner text and remove the surrounding HTML?

Comment: Can you modify your code?

Comment: This question is not similar to the link provided link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of faffing about with regex use the DOM:

```js
const str = '<span class="resource-child-type">device</span> (<span class="resource-child-instance">10.212.7.161</span>) &gt; interface (<span class="resource-child-instance">10.212.7.161_interface:&lt;10&gt;</span>)';

// Create a temporary element
const temp = document.createElement('div');

// Set the string to the element's innerHTML
temp.innerHTML = str;

// Find the instances of resource-child-instance in the documet
const instances = temp.querySelectorAll('.resource-child-instance');

// Iterate over each element
instances.forEach((node) => {

  // Replace each node with it's own textContent
  node.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(node.textContent))
});

// The output
console.log(temp.innerHTML);
```

Comment: I understand that we should try to avoid using Regex to strip HTML from strings. However, in my case, the HTML is not rendered but instead, is passed around between a few javascript functions (it's a leftover of legacy codes)

Comment: I just quickly updated the answer to use a temporary element. This is by far the easiest method. I think you'll really struggle with regex.

Comment: Yep just tried. Works great!